# Can i store select query result into a list variable in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For Example,

```
set output_var;
select name from customer limit 5;

aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

is it possible to store this output into a variable(output_var), So that my output looks like

```
output_var = (aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't store the result set from a query in anything other than a table in the Web GUI, or unload to cloud storage.   Well, you can export a result set to CSV using the GUI, but SQL variables only accept constant expressions, not queries.

You can always use tables to store intermediate results, if you have the grants.

If you are using a client, eg. the Python client, you have access to result sets as a data stucture in the Python script and can use the data however you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert as below :

cur=snflk_conn.cursor()
sql_query='select NAME from TEST"'

without Panda:
result  = cur.execute(sql_query)
list1=[]
for res in result:
    list1.append(res[0])
print(list1)

using Panda:
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, snflk_conn)
print(df)
print(df.values.tolist())
print(list(df['NAME']))